# JMeter 4.0 Unable to perform distributed testing after disabling (server.rmi.ssl.disable)

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, distributed, jmeter-4.0

Steps I performed:

1. In Master as well as in Slave : In `jmeter.properties`  file configured `server.rmi.ssl.disable=true` and uncommented it.
2. Master as well as in Slave : In `jmeter.properties` file uncommented  `server.rmi.ssl.keystore.password=changeit`
3. Restarted Master as well as Slave.
4. Ran `jmeter-server.bat` file on slave.
5. Case A: From Master ran `Slave(172.XX.XX.XX)` from GUI.

   Case B: Path of bin folder>`jmeter -n -t <Path of .jmx  file> -R 172.XX.XX.XX -l E:<Path of Result file> -Gusers=1000 -Grampup=100`

**Execution result:**

Case A: Test Starts on Slave and finishes as well but in the Result file there is no Data found.

Case B: Created the tree successfully using < Path of .jmx file >.jmx

```
Configuring remote engine: 172.XX.XX.XX
Starting remote engines
Starting the test @ Wed Oct 24 22:47:55 IST 2018 (1540401475258)
Remote engines have been started
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up remote @ Wed Oct 24 22:48:05 IST 2018 (1540401485415)
... end of run
```

Also, result file gets generated but there no Data in it.

Note: 
1.  Master and Slave are in same subnet.

2. Master : java version `"1.8.0_151"`

   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)

   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
3. Slave : java version `"1.8.0_161"`

   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)

   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
4. I am testing web application(HTTPS) application.

Can anyone help me on this please, I’m I doing any mistake while configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should always run server and client with same version of Java, that’s not the case here.

Second, if by Data is empty, you mean Reponse Data is empty then it is the expected behavior, in distributed testing, jmeter strips response data for performances , but you’ll have other informations like metrics, error status...

Finally, if issue persists show:

- jmeter-server.log
- jmeter.log
- output of client and server

Comment: Thank you so much UBIK LOAD PACK, logs were the saviour for me.

Comment: Happy it helped. You can also upvote. For my information what did logs reveal ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for late response UBIK LOAD PACK. Yes,log revealed that I need to keep copy of a CSV file in the respective slaves for the test to execute on them.As the test plan covers the functionality which has been implemented with the concept of parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps
1) Copy the generated rmi_keystore.jks to jmeter bin folder
2) Add slave Ip address in jmeter.properties
3) run jmeter-server file in slave system
4) go to run in master jmeter and run

I have added the following path in create-rmi-keystore.bat file "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\keytool" -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias rmi -keystore rmi_keystore.jks -storepass changeit -validity 7 -keysize 2048 %*

go to cmd run as administrator
cd > D:\Performance testing\apache-jmeter-5.0\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\create-rmi-keystore
enter

then run in command prompt
Enter first name and last name : rmi
password : changeit

Comment: Hi kalpesh, I'm unable to generate rmi_keystore.jks using create-rmi-keystore.bat could you help me with the steps to generate rmi_keystore.jks please. Currently I have disabled (server.rmi.ssl.disable) by uncommenting and setting it to TRUE in user.properties file of both Master as well as Salve.

Comment: sagar, You can easily generate the rmi_keystore.jk in Mac, After generating the same file you can transfer to windows system.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, I'm able to generate rmi_keystore.jks. I have a query, that does it makes difference from the point of view of testing HTTPS application, if we disable(server.rmi.ssl.disable) and run the load test on single machine or in Distributed mode of testing.

Comment: Sagar, rmi_keystore.jk file is used only for the purpose of distributing load testing. If you disabled then the normal form of testing can be done but not distributed.